# Mod_rewrite still not ignore existing files/folders

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this for another site and works no issues. But just loaded onto a new site, custom built and it's not working, whenever I go to a directory that actually exists on the server or a CSS/JS file, it comes up 403 Forbidden.

**UPDATE: I've found everything except for two js documents and one css document is working fine, those 3 are still getting the 403 Forbidden error. Any suggestions on a fix? .htaccess file seems to be working fine, I think it may be a Permissions issue, but I've checked and everything checks out fine....**

**UPDATE 2: I've found the issue, it's to do with the FilesMatch block of code, if you have any item in there, eg: (ini|log|foo), even though it does not explicitly define a specific word, if that part of the word is in the filename and it matches it will give a 403 Forbidden error, for example, above we have ini, log and foo, if you have a file with extension for example, .foodItem, it will detect the foo and block the file entirely and give a 403, so just remember that... ISSUE HAS NOW BEEN RESOLVED, notes in UPDATE 2 on Solution for anyone else who runs into this issue.**

Below is the HTACCESS file, please if anyone can help solve this, I would be very delighted! I also need it to block hotlinking and also cache files automatically.

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectoryIndex index.html

<FilesMatch ".(clb|ini|log|data)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `Options -Indexes` will cause the *403 Forbidden* message for directories. As for existing files, it should work... Oh, and you don't need the `RewriteBase` line, and your two `DirectoryIndex` lines can be merged into one: `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've adjusted and re-uploaded to the Server, didn't seem to make any change? Hmmm. Thoughts? Thanks for taking the time to assist, I appreciate it a lot!!!

Comment: What version of Apache are you running? And are you using a virtual host?

Comment: Apache version 2.4.7 and yes, it's a VirtualHost.

Comment: Stupid thing is, I am using exactly the same .htaccess file on another site that runs on the same code on the same server and it's having no problems, I even cloned the config across and mirrored the vhost file and obviously updated the paths and server names etc and still not working???

Comment: Hmm, weird indeed. Is your `index.php` rule working? Unfortunately, I'm not an Apache expert (even though I use it), so I would naturally - much like you - assume that it should work.

Comment: I have checked other css and js files in the source code by clicking, open in new tab, and all other documents on the site work fine, just a very small handful, unfortunately, the ones primarily required are affected.

Comment: I've noticed only 3 of the css/js documents are getting a 403, everything else is working fine? Could it be a permissions issue and how do I resolve since residing on Ubuntu Server, Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the reason it didn't work on this site and it worked on the other was because I had .init.js and .init.css in the filenames of the affected files, where it has FilesMatch in the htaccess file, because "ini" is present in the filename of those files, it gave the 403 Forbidden error. The issue has now been resolved and I had to remove the "ini" from the FilesMatch list.

Comment: That explains it. Even better, just use `<FilesMatch ".(clb|ini|log|data)$">`